# Vue2 unit test in PhantomJS, how to send keys or trigger event?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, vuejs2

I have a simple search box in my component and I would like to unit test the behaviour when text is typed in the search box.

**Template**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="filterBox" v-on:input="updateFilter">
```

**Unit test**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Grid from 'src/components/Grid';

function create (Component, propsData) {
  const Ctor = Vue.extend(Component);
  return new Ctor({ propsData }).$mount();
}

describe('Grid.vue', () => {
  it('should debounce search', () => {
    const vm = create(Grid, {
      data: [],
      columns: [],
      initialSortKey: 'a'
    });
    var box = vm.$el.querySelector('#filterBox');
    //TODO figure out how to send keys
  });
});
```

I am using Vue2 and PhantomJS for unit tests. How can I send keys to the input box or trigger a value change event?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use jQuery.

```
var e = $.Event('keydown');
e.which = 56; // whatever keycode you need here
$('#filterBox').trigger(e);
```

So now you need to do this repeatedly. But this is how you trigger the event.